# SQL multiple constrained counts in query

Tags: sql, select, count, where-clause

I am trying to get with 1 query multiple count results where each one is a subset of the previous one.

So my table would be called `Recipe` and has these columns:

```
recipe_num(Primary_key) decimal, 
recipe_added date,
is_featured bit,
liked decimal
```

And what I want is to make a query that will return the amount of likes grouped by day for any particular month with

- total recipes as total_recipes,
- total recipes that were featured as featured_recipes,
- total number of recipes that were featured and had more than 100 likes liked_recipes

So as you can see each they are all counts with each being a subset of the previous one.

Ideally I don't want to run separate select count's where that query the whole table but rather get from the previous one.

I am not very good at using count with Where, Having, etc... and not exactly sure how to do it, so far I have the following which I managed via digging around here.

```
select 
    recipe_added, 
    count(*) total_recipes, 
    count(case is_featured when 1 then 1 else null end) total_featured_recipes
from  
    RECIPES 
group by 
    recipe_added
```

I am not exactly sure why I have to use case inside the count but I wasn't able to get it to work using WHERE, would like to know if this is possible as well.

Thanks

Comment: calculation of a month from a date column is specific to your DBMS...

Comment: @marc_s, I must appreciate the effort you spent on making the post better readble. But the formatting of SQL queries are not proper and with bigger query it takes much space in terms of new line and we should save space here what I feel.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30: I value **readability** (and thus maintainability) of code **much higher** any day than "saving space" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `CASE` expression inside `COUNT()` you are doing conditional aggregation and this is exactly what you need for this requirement:

```
select recipe_added, 
       count(*) total_recipes, 
       count(case when is_featured = 1 then 1 end) total_featured_recipes,
       count(case when is_featured = 1 and liked > 100 then 1 end) liked_recipes
from Recipes 
group by recipe_added
```

There is no need for `ELSE null` because the default behavior of a `CASE` expression is to return `null` when no other branch returns a value.

If you want results for a specific month, say October 2020, you can add a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`:

```
where format(recipe_added, 'yyyyMM') = '202010'
```

This will work for SQL Server.
If you are using a different database then you can use a similar approach.

Comment: Hi, every count is still a separate count that iterates over the whole table though it seems, isn't there a way for the 2nd and 3rd count to iterate over the previous count and not the whole table?

Comment: Every count does not iterate the whole table. It iterates the group it is defined on with the `group by` clause.

Comment: Also why is conditional aggregation the way to go here exactly?

Comment: `count(*)` is not conditional aggregation because it counts everything. `count(case ... end)` is conditional aggregation because you want to count only if a certain condition is true.

Comment: how come count...where doesn't work though, that would be conditional as well no?

Comment: is iterating on the group each count the most efficient way for this then? is there no way to iterate on the previous count which is a smaller set?

Comment: *how come count...where doesn't work though* there is no `count(...where..)` valid sql syntax. There is `count(*) filter (where...)` in databases like Postgresql or SQLite, but this is also conditional aggregation. *is iterating on the group each count the most efficient way for this then?* yes it is the most efficient way. You could also use window function COUNT() but you would also need to add DISTINCT in the SELECT statement which would make it less efficient. *is there no way to iterate on the previous count which is a smaller set?* the previous count() is just a function, not a group.